# By taking a quick glance, do you think this mathematical book is educational and credible?

Tags: education

Long story short, when I was in High school I thought that Mathematics were not for me and that's why I had a hard time studying but as I grew I realized that I was just too lazy to study it and I would like to correct that mistake. I have begun studying from this book : http://www.everythingmaths.co.za/maths/grade-10  and I intend to fully finish it before starting with grade 11, grade 12 and so on. The only concern that I have is that it might not be the best possible resource. Do you guys think it's OK and if not, could you recommend some good books for 10th graders. Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually, as we grow older, we are less dependent of our learning resources. Elem. and High School resources for students usually have heavy guidance (specially in elem.), because we expect those students to not have yet the abilities to guide their study themselves. I don't know your background or experience, but following a high school book could be a tedious or demotivating thing to do. If you feel confortable, I would suggest using the book as a 'content guide', and independently studying each topic outside the context of a 'textbook'. You can use the exercises to evaluate yourself.